# Hibernate HQL returns no appropriate constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have HQL query

```
select new PaymentType(o.paymentType.idPaymentType) from Order as o where o.user='1'
```

it throws following exception

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: PaymentType
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.renderSQL(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:631)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
```

But I have declared required constructor, except of this, there are declared other tree constructors with different count and types of params, and also no params constructor.

```
public PaymentType(Integer idPaymentType) {
    this.idPaymentType = idPaymentType;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
public class Order  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer idOrder;
     private PaymentType paymentType;
     private DeliveryType deliveryType;
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

two things worth to check.
1.try use a fully qualified name of PaymentType

```
select new com.company.xxx.PaymentType(o.paymentType.idPaymentType)
```

2.also make sure the id in entity **Order** is **int/integer** rather than **Long** or something else.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. #1 don't work. #2 How can I get type of `o.paymentType.idPaymentType`.

Comment: could you attache the code of Order.java? I assume there is a field called **paymentType**. what is the type of **idPaymentType** field in **PaymentType.java**?

Comment: I've edited it. `idPaymentType` of `PaymentType` is `Integer`.

Comment: is PaymentType also a entity? if so, why not just use "select o.paymentType from Order as o where o.user='1' "

Comment: yes, it is a entity. But I want to get only `idPaymentType`. Therefore I'm solving this problem.

Comment: is **org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: PaymentType** the root exception? could you attach the full exception trace. I've written a testing case based on your code, and everything works fine to me. I wonder if the issue is actually caused by something else, such as the column type in underlying DB is not integer.

Comment: Yes, it is root exception. Look on updated question. I note that I use HQL Query window in netbeans, but I had with this tool no problem so far .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24651/discussion-between-spiritwalker-and-misco)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this exception before working with Hibernate.  From what I recall, it either has to do with not having the parameter-less constructor, the parameter-less constructor not having public acccess, or your entity class not being serializable.

Try the following:

1. Make sure you have these constructors in `PaymentType` class:

   ```
   /** 
    * Default, parameter-less constructor
    */
   public PaymentType() {
   }
   ```
2. And also for `Order`:

   ```
   /** 
    * Default, parameter-less constructor
    */
   public Order() {
   }
   ```
3. Make sure that both `PaymentType` and `Order` implement `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: I checked your notes. Everything was defined, I absolutelly don't understand.

Comment: @misco is your class `PaymentType` public?

Comment: yes, it is public. I can make HQL query for all fields `PaymentType`, but I want to get only `IdPaymentType` for `Order`.